# How would I give someone a role using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I know this has been asked before but my question is a little different, how would I make a command that gives *someone else* a role? For example

```
[p]giverole @user
```

would give them a role? I know how to give roles to the author using discord.py but cannot figure out how to give it to the person mentioned. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to use arguments in commands like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
 # if no member is provided, the bot will give the role to the cmd author
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(112233445566778899) # role ID goes there
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully gave {member} the {role.name} role!")
```

This is preferred over using the `on_message()` event because it can be much easier to deal with arguments when using commands registered with decorators.

---

**References:**

- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+
- [`Guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: thanks! i'm probably missing something small but i'm getting the error

`name 'discord' is not defined`

would you mind helping?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply ‍♀️and no... that fixed it, pretty dumb on my part haha

Comment: Haha no worries! Glad you've got it working now! Happy coding :^)